# C# Winforms Shorter Way to Add Items into ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

May I know is there a shorter way to add items to the comboBox? Currently I am only adding 20 items which already seems very long, what if I have a 100 items to add into the comboBox?

My code:

```
private void loadSharePricesComboBox()
{
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("BARC");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("DEB");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("DOM");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("EZJ");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("GFS");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("IHG");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("JD.");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("LAD");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("LLOY");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("MRW");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("NXT");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("OCDO");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("RBS");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("SMWH");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("SPD");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("STAN");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("SYR");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("TALK");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("TSCO");
    comboComSymbol.Items.Add("WMH");

    comboComSymbol.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Your help is much appreciated! Thank you. :)

Addition code (for the question i asked Simon Whitehead):

```
private void btnDownloadXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile("http://www.lse.co.uk/chat/" + comboDownloadXML.SelectedItem,
                            @"..\..\sharePriceXML\" + comboDownloadXML.SelectedItem + ".xml");
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Download Completed! File has been placed in the folder sharePriceXML!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save on code size.. why not list them in a file?

```
void loadSharePricesComboBox(string fileName) {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
            comboComSymbol.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: In response to your comment.. I would just load the files, without extensions.. that would be much easier:

```
void loadSharePricesComboBox(string path) {
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml")) {
        comboComSymbol.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }
}
```

Pass in the path you want to load the XML file names from, perhaps like this:

```
loadSharePricesComboBox(@"..\..\sharePriceXML\");
```

This will load all the XML file names, without their extensions, giving you the list you require.

Comment: this is a good idea to me. But i have another question after you introduced me this method. I download .xml files (I added the code in my initial question, please take a look). How can I write the files name (without .xml extension) into the file automatically, then read it using your code?

Comment: Or, how do I directly show the downloaded files' names into comboComSymbol?

Comment: It only downloads one file doesn't it? Can you give me an example of the full URL you download the XML from?

Comment: What I intended to do is, if a user choose LLOY from a list (not the above questioned combobox dropdown list), then he clicks Download button, then the LLOY.xml will be downloaded to the folder sharePriceXML. I was hoping to create automatic way to add this word "LLOY" into a file (maybe .txt file), then use your suggested code to read the lines in this .txt file which will then show on the comboBox dropdown list. `"http://www.lse.co.uk/chat/" + comboDownloadXML.SelectedItem`. If you refer to my question up there again, you will see I put up the code of my download function. Thanks.

Comment: it works and it is indeed cleaner and more useful, but when a user downloaded the .xml file into the folder and go back to choose from comboBoxSymbol, the newly downloaded .xml file doesn't appear in the list, the comboComSymbol list doesn't update at runtime. is there a way to do a refresh or something? :|

Comment: Clear the combobox at the start of the function I gave you.. then just call that function every time you want it to refresh.

Comment: I put `comboComSymbol.Items.Clear();
                loadSharePricesComboBox(@"..\..\sharePriceXML\");` in `btnDownloadXML_Click` function and it works. :) So whenever I downloaded a new xml file, the `comboComSymbol` will clear and then load again or something like refresh. I hope I am doing it right, please tell me if this code is not good enough. Thank you Simon!

Comment: Only thing I would change us moving the clearing of the combo box into the load function. You're welcome :)

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work in my case. Thus, I put it under the btnDownloadXML_Click.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `AddRange()` method?

I haven't tested:

```
private void loadSharePricesComboBox()
{

     comboComSymbol.Items.AddRange(new string[]{"BARC", "DEB", ... etc});

    comboComSymbol.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

The MSDN on [`.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange.aspx) might give you a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in "BARC,DEB,DOM,...".Split(',')) comboComSybol.Items.Add(item);
```

or

```
var items = new [] { "BARC", "DEV", "DOM" };
foreach(var item in items) comboComSymbol.Items.Add(item);
```

or you can save even more code and use AddRange on the above 2 methods.

```
var items = new [] { "BARC", "DEV", "DOM" };
comboComSymbol.Items.AddRange(items);
```

If you are starting a new project though, have a look at WPF instead of winforms.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. :) Thanks. But why do you suggest WPF? I am very new to programming, my friend introduced me Winforms.

Comment: @Shyuan There is a world of difference between WPF and winforms. Winforms is now very dated. WPF is much more powerful and flexible. It's hard to describe in the comments here but if you are new to programming you may as well start with the newest. The downside is that it could be considered more difficult but only because there are so many more options.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az.aspx)
You can use it like this:
`comboComSymbol.Items.AddRange(new string[] {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"});`

Answer (score 0):

use generic `List<T>` to databind.

```
class Symbols
{
public string Name{get;set;}
}

var Symb= new List<Symbols> { new Symbols() { Name = "Abc"}, new Person() { Name = "BC" }};
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.DataSource = Symb;
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", Symb, "Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

this code :

```
string[] str = {
                "BARC","DEB","DOM","EZJ","GFS","IHG","JD.","LAD","LLOY","MRW",
                "NXT","OCDO","RBS","SMWH","SPD","STAN","SYR","TALK","TSCO","WMH"
                };


 loadSharePricesComboBox(str);
```

your method :

```
private void loadSharePricesComboBox(string[] strArr)
    {
        comboComSymbol.Items.AddRange(strArr);
        comboComSymbol.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```